# Javascript - Object Array unique and appropriate filtering

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter a JSON object for my Cinema App I am creating as a Portfolio piece however I am having difficulties.
I have managed to get a unique JSON object however I cannot get a unique object with a condition, the condition being -
Only return a JSON object that contains dates for the selected Movie.
Currently, all dates are featuring, even ones for other irrelevant movies.

[HTML View to understand the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT8BU.jpg)

Before Filtering

```
[{"ShowtimeId":"1","Date":"2019-02-13","Time":"14:00:00","MovieId":"1","Title":"Black Panther","Genre":"Superhero","Duration":"100","Rating":"5","Description":"Movies","Actors":""},{"ShowtimeId":"2","Date":"2019-02-13","Time":"15:29:35","MovieId":"1","Title":"Black Panther","Genre":"Superhero","Duration":"100","Rating":"5","Description":"Movies","Actors":""},{"ShowtimeId":"3","Date":"2019-02-20","Time":"14:11:29","MovieId":"2","Title":"Antman","Genre":"Superhero","Duration":"120","Rating":"5","Description":"Decent","Actors":"Brad Pitt"}]
```

After Filtering 
My JSON Array looks like this (unqiueDate):

```
`[{"ShowtimeId":"1","Date":"2019-02-13","Time":"14:00:00","MovieId":"1","Title":"Black Panther","Genre":"Superhero","Duration":"100","Rating":"5","Description":"Movies","Actors":""},{"ShowtimeId":"3","Date":"2019-02-20","Time":"14:11:29","MovieId":"2","Title":"Antman","Genre":"Superhero","Duration":"120","Rating":"5","Description":"Decent","Actors":"Brad Pitt"}]`
```

I have already tried techniques to filter however each time I am presented with an undefined variable, due to the function not operating as I expected.

Method 1:
Create a search function to search the array and return a filtered array, then try and populate the input

```
`
relevantDate = search(MovieTitle,
  for(var i=0;i<uniqueDate.length;++i){
    //Unique Dates and Relevant Dates
    document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+relevantDate[i].Date+'</option>';
     }
//Loop Over Array
        function search(nameKey, myArray){
        for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
                return myArray[i];
            }
        }`
```

Method 2:

Use the .find() method to filter the array

```
`relevantDate = search(MovieTitle,
  for(var i=0;i<uniqueDate.length;++i){
    //Unique Dates and Relevant Dates
    document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+relevantDate[i].Date+'</option>';`

`relevantDate = arr.find(o => o.name === MovieTitle);`
```

HTML-

```
`div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 fast-drop">
                        <select class="form-control" name="Select Film" id="Title" onchange="FastSearch()">
                            <option selected disabled>Select Film</option>
                            <!-- <option>Mary Poppins</option> -->
                        </select>
                    </div>`

` <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 fast-drop">
                        <select class="form-control" name="Select Date" id="Date"  onchange="FastSearch()" disabled>
                            <option selected disabled>Select Date</option>
                            <!-- <option>21/01</option> -->
                        </select>
                    </div>
`
```

Javascript -

```
`var arr = new Array();
        var Title = "";
        var MovieTitle = "";
        var checked = 0; //Determines which DOM elements have been selected
        let uniqueDate = {};
        let relevantDate = {};`

`$.ajax(
            {
                url: '../Controller/Movies.php',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    var Title = data.Title;
                    arr = JSON.parse(data);
                    let unique = arr.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.Title) && set.add(f.Title))(new Set));
                    for(var i=0;i<unique.length;++i){
                        //New Options for Showtime movies
                        document.getElementById('Title').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+unique[i].Title+'</option>';
                        //document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+arr[i].Date+'</option>';
                        //document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+arr[i].Time+'</option>';
                    }
                    console.table(arr);
                }
            });`


`function FastSearch()
        {
            MovieTitle = $("#Title :selected").text();`

            `switch(checked)
            {
                case 0: //When Movie is selected, Add 1 and activate the date field
                        //if title selected
                        if(MovieTitle.length >= 1)
                        {
                            $('#Date').removeAttr('disabled');
                            uniqueDate = arr.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.Date) && set.add(f.Date))(new Set));
                            relevantDate = search(MovieTitle,uniqueDate);
                            for(var i=0;i<uniqueDate.length;++i){
                                //Unique Dates and Relevant Dates
                                document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML += '<option value='+i+'>'+relevantDate[i].Date+'</option>';
                        }
                            checked++;
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#Date').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $('#Time').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }

                        break;
                case 1:
                        //alert('test');
            }
        }`


`//Loop Over Array
        function search(nameKey, myArray){
        for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
                return myArray[i];
            }
        }`
```

I expected the array to be returned in the form of `relevantDate` to be a JSON object with only unique filtered values.

I have looked at other stackoverflow questions and I cannot find an answer that fits.

Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: So you want to sort the array of objects by duplicates?

Comment: I have already sorted the array by duplicates. Now I am trying to sort the array to only show Movie Dates for a selected Movie. Currently it is showing all Dates for all Movies even when a specific Movie is selected.

Comment: What is input and expected output of `uniqueDate`? Is `uniqueData` a `JSON` string or a JavaScript plain object?

Comment: I updated the question to have the input of unique date and the output is the one that was already present. It contains an js plain array object of all the non-duplicate dates for movies.

Comment: No object in the array has a property named `"name"` though that is the property name used in the code to match at `myArray[i].name === nameKey` and `o.name === MovieTitle`. Are you trying to match the property `"Title"`?

Comment: That is an error in copying the code over. With this function it only returns the first object that it finds instead of all the objects it finds. Only finding the first one means that the exact same object is returned each time. But yes I am trying to match the property Title